# Binding polymer paper-dropdown-menu to localstorage

Tags: data-binding, drop-down-menu, polymer, web-component, paper-elements

## Admittedly silly-seeming question... And...

before anyone hastily replies, "**RTFM**," I have yet I still don't quite grok it -- data-binding.

---

So, I've got a sort of form, which is really a component consisting of inputs and whatnot *and also* a `core-localstorage` element. I've successfully persisted the values of other inputs between sessions, yet I've gotten fuzzy on the `paper-dropdown-menu`. gridlocked...

**What I want to do is use the `label` for the display value, and when the `machine in machines` bit is going, I want the selected `paper-item` to reflect the value from local storage (the label)**

Oh, and this is in jade, btw. Here's how it's looking:

```
//- JADE

  /** Stuff that works: **/

    core-localstorage(id='storage', name='vbms-user-settings', value='{{settings}}')

    .subhead General
    paper-input(floatingLabel, label='Username', inputValue='{{settings.username}}', on-change='{{updateStorage}}')
    paper-input(floatingLabel, label='Password', inputValue='{{settings.password}}', on-change='{{updateStorage}}', type='password')

    paper-checkbox#vpn_gui_toggle.accent(label='Run Headless', checked, style='margin-right: 16px;')

  /** The confusing input **/

    paper-dropdown-menu#vm_dropdown(valueattr='label', on-core-select='{{updateDefaultVM}}')
        template(repeat="{{machine in machines}}")
            paper-item(label="{{machine.name}}")
```

### Here's some js... this works fine; i'm trying to do things the "dogmatic" Polymer way.

```
    /*\  JS 
    |*| ...blah blah polymer jank... 
    \*/ 

    objectToStorage: function(obj) {
        this.$.storage.value=obj;
        this.$.storage.save();
    },
    updateStorage: function() {
        this.objectToStorage(this.settings);
    },
    updateDefaultVM: function() {}
```

Can anyone lead me to the most-probably simple solution to this hangup?!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the recommended way of using `<paper-dropdown-menu>` is to have a two layers of containers between it and the `<paper-item>`s, based on the example from the [current docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/paper-elements.html#paper-dropdown-menu).

If you're using that setup, you've now got a [`<core-menu>`](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-menu), which inherits from [`<core-selector>`](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-selector). Things that inherit from `<core-selector>` can make use of the `selected` attribute to control which item is selected. But `<core-selected>` defaults to checking to see if any of the items it contains has a `name` attribute whose value matches the `selected` value, so we also need to add in `name` attributes to all of the `<paper-item>`s.

The end result of something simple, that doesn't rely on loading in values from `<core-localstorage>`, looks like the following. You should be able to do something similar if you're loading in the initial value from `<core-localstorage>` instead of hardcoding it.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Polymer Demo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="//www.polymer-project.org/webcomponents.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="//www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-dropdown-menu/paper-dropdown-menu.html">
    <link rel="import" href="//www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-dropdown/paper-dropdown.html">
    <link rel="import" href="//www.polymer-project.org/components/core-menu/core-menu.html">
    <link rel="import" href="//www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-item/paper-item.html">
    
    <template id="page-template" is="auto-binding">
      <h1>Pastry Menu</h1>
      <paper-dropdown-menu label="Your favorite pastry">
        <paper-dropdown class="dropdown">
          <core-menu class="menu" selected="{{initiallySelected}}">
            <template repeat="{{pastry in pastries}}">
              <paper-item name="{{pastry}}">{{pastry}}</paper-item>
            </template>
          </core-menu>
        </paper-dropdown>
      </paper-dropdown-menu>
    </template>

    <script>
      var pageTemplate = document.querySelector('#page-template');
      pageTemplate.pastries = [
        'Croissant',
        'Donut',
        'Financier',
        'Madeleine'
      ];
      
      // Set this to whatever you want the initially selected item to be. It's value can be loaded from localStorage.
      pageTemplate.initiallySelected = 'Financier';
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great answer! It's not often I read an answer meant to teach rather than flex muscles. Very much appreciated, and it makes total sense now. +1